# calculate the number of weeks between start date and end date using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, mean-stack

I want to show the number of weeks between the start date and end date can anyone tell me how can I do this I am using the reactive form module and I am taking input from the user

my HTML code is here

```html
<div class="my-3">
                                    
<label class="form-label" for="Pen_sDate">{{l("sDate")}} *</label>
                                    <input type="date"  id="Pen_sDate" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pen.sDate" formControlName="sDate"     required/>

                                </div>

                                <div class="my-3">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="Pen_eDate">{{l("eDate")}} *</label>
                                    <input type="date"  id="Pen_eDate" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pen.eDate" name="eDate" formControlName="eDate"     required/>

                                </div>
```

{{l("sDate")}} *

```
                            </div>

                            <div class="my-3">
                                <label class="form-label" for="Pen_eDate">{{l("eDate")}} *</label>
                                <input type="date"  id="Pen_eDate" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pen.eDate" name="eDate" formControlName="eDate"     required/>

                            </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your inputs are connected to Date variables you can do this:

```
let daysDiff = (this.pen.eDate.getTime() - this.pen.sDate.getTime()) 
               / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

getTime() returns the nr of milliseconds since 01-01-1970. To get the number of days you have to divide by 1000ms * 60s * 60m * 24h. If you want to get only full days you have to apply a floor (Math.floor()) or round (Math.round()) function.

The weeks is just a division of 7 away…